# ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) making writes slower?

Tags: c++, iostream

I wrote some minimal code to test the effect of setting `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;

#ifdef NO_SYNC_STDIO
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
#endif

#ifdef READ
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
#else
    line = "123456";
    for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++)
#endif

#ifdef WRITE
        std::cout << line << "\n";
#else
        1;
#endif

    return 1;
}
```

These are the results of `time [yes 123456 | sed 10000000q | ] ./stdstream-dummy > /dev/null`:

```
      -DREAD -DWRITE  -DREAD   -DWRITE
real     24.963s      4.622s   0.950s
user     22.514s      6.732s   0.942s
sys       4.825s      0.313s   0.008s
```

With `-DNO_SYNC_STDIO`:

```
      -DREAD -DWRITE  -DREAD   -DWRITE
real     38.327s      1.865s   1.223s
user     29.835s      3.990s   1.180s
sys      10.875s      0.351s   0.043s
```

As can be seen, the time degrades a bit if I have to *write*. Any insights?

Some extra info:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ uname -a
SunOS cfprepagop01 5.10 Generic_148888-05 sun4v sparc sun4v

$ ldd stdstream-dummy
    libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/sfw/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/sfw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
    /lib/libm/libm_hwcap1.so.2
    /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

Comment: Off-topic I know but how is `std::sync_with_stdio` possible? `sync_with_stdio` is declared in `ios_base` and only accessible as a static member function of it and its derived classes.

Comment: I'm wondering the same; the closest I could get is `cout.sync_with_stdio(false)`. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will enlighten us.

Comment: `cout` is a `basic_ostream` which is a derived class of `ios_base`, so that makes sense. It might just be a provision of your implementation (which frankly is quite outdated).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! I pasted non-working code. Will fix at once.